# Developing Mediaplayer for windows 8 phone

Tags: windows-8, windows-mobile, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am newbie to windows-8 phone development.
My first assignment is to develop mediaplayer for windows 8 phone.
can anyone guide me how should I proceed?
The requirement for mediaplayer is as follows.

1. Mediaplayer should have ability to stream the music from server.
2. We need to cache last played music-track by mediaplayer.
3. functionality like playnext,playprev,playlist etc..

Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Assignment from who? Personal or?

Comment: It is a project for client.

Comment: So you want _us_ to earn _your_ money?

Comment: Good timing: we just released the Microsoft Player Framework for Windows Phone 8 yesterday. It's an open source media player project built by Microsoft. You can download it from http://playerframework.codeplex.com

Comment: @Tim Greenfield Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you have is a basic exercise in coding.

Take a nice long read through the Media Overview for Windows Phone.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402550(VS.92).aspx .  You'll have to implement your cache, probably in isolated storage.  The playnext, playprevious you'll have to do as well.

Work through some of the basic tutorials up at genapp in the phone section for some free training.  http://bit.ly/30tolaunch .